# Scroll Array onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

excusme if the question is Amateur . 
In click on Button must the background color of button  change to 3 Colors . 
I use Array , in first click must Color be a Red , second click Blue , Black and reset
So i must scroll the Array from index 0 . 
this is a Code but dosent work .

```
var color = ['red','blue','black'];
var calo = function() {
   for (var i=0 ; i<color.length ; i++)
    {
    return color[i];
    }  
};

var farbe = function(){
    return color[calo()]; 
};

    $('#c2').click(function() {
            $(this).css('background',farbe());
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
var color = ['red', 'blue', 'black'];
var colorIndex = 2;
$('#c2').click(function () {
    switch (colorIndex) {
        case 0:
            $('#c2').css('background', color[1]);
            colorIndex += 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#c2').css('background', color[2]);
            colorIndex += 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#c2').css('background', color[0]);
            colorIndex = 0;
            break;
    }

});
```

I didn't test this but I think it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of global variable to track the current color:

```
var currentColorIndex = 0;

var color = ['red','blue','black'];
var calo = function() {
    currentColorIndex++;
    if (currentColorIndex >= color.length) {
        currentColorIndex = 0;
    }  

    // alternative
    // currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex++) % color.length;

    return currentColorIndex;
};

var farbe = function(){
    return color[calo()]; 
};

$('#c2').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color',farbe());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61rfpt51/)

Comment: The code I had copied from the OP was incorrect. Fixed that, and fixed the return value on the calo method. Added working Fiddle.